# Jax-RS Client to consume public API

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Today I want to consume public API and handle it with Jax RS usage. 
This particular API require header with

So far, I based on this tutorial:
[Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client)
but there is a problem with the line:

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.get(RecipeIngredient.class);
```

IntelliJ informs that part of the assignment contains a problem like:

```
Incompatible types. Required response but get was inferred to T: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that RecipeIngredient conform to response
```

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@RestController
public class NutritionixApiController {

    @GetMapping("/productDetails")
    public ResponseEntity<RecipeIngredient> getProductDetails(@RequestParam String product) {

        // added header
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set("x-app-id", new NutritionixHeader().getNutritionixAppId());
        header.set("x-app-key", new NutritionixHeader().getNutritionixAppKey());

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get(RecipeIngredient.class);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).build();
    }
}
```

This endpoint requires header with appId, appKey and param which will be the name of a product. After all, we suppose to receive a collection of products which matched to the product name.

RecipeIngredient.class

```
@Getter
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecipeIngredient {

    private final Long id;
    private final String foodName;
    private final Integer servingQty;
    private final String servingUnit;
    private final Integer servingWeightGrams;
    private final List<String> fullNutrients;
    private final String brandName;
    private final String nixBrandId;
    private final Integer upc;
    private final String note;
    private final Integer source;
    private final List<String> altMeasures;
}
```

I'll be grateful, for pieces of advice how I suppose to change the code from the controller to receive desirable effect with a collection of product information from the outside consumed API. If you know any better solution to achieve this goal feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: The tutorial seems to be off. Either use `RecipeIngredient item = invocationBuilder.get(RecipeIngredient.class);` or `RecipeIngredient item = invocationBuilder.get().readEntity(RecipeIngredient.class);`

Comment: @sfiss Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to cast this to the set of RecipeIngredients? 

`
https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/
`

I have this tutorial but honestly, I cannot see the point how to cast it.

If I understand properly I suppose to create an additional entity with a collection of this Ingredients and handle it.

Comment: Ok, typical blond moment. Now it seems that syntax is ok.

`
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        RecipeIngredientsCollection item = invocationBuilder.get(RecipeIngredientsCollection.class);
        Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = item.getRecipeIngredientCollection();
`